# numpy zeros error - TypeError: data type not understood for np.zeros

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pickle

```
   dir_path='/home/jeevitha/8_8_192_features'
    #count = 1
    for name in os.listdir(dir_path):
    #count += 1
    video_id = name.split('.')[0]
    fname='/home/jeevitha/8_8_192_features'+video_id+'.pkl'
    if not (os.path.isfile(fname) ):
        video_file_path=os.path.join(dir_path, name)
        features=open(video_file_path, 'rb')  
        features=list() 
        new_features = np.zeros(8,8,192)
        for i in features:
            new_features+=features[i]
        new_features=new_features/len(features)
        dump(features,open(fname,'wb'))
```

please help me , to store pickle file using np.zeros

i tried 
importing math and numpy
still error shows like "data type not understood"

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
new_features = np.zeros([8,8,192])
```

edit:
There is more stuff wrong with this snippet.

```
features=open(video_file_path, 'rb')  
features=list() #remove this. debug code?
new_features = np.zeros(8,8,192)
for i in features:
    new_features+=features[i]
new_features=new_features/len(features)
dump(features,open(fname,'wb'))
```

features is set to an empty list and saved. 
Moreover, I guess you wanna save new_features?

Comment: new_features = np.zeros([8,8,192])
if i run as above the following code, the pickle feature shape shows (0,), instead of (8,8,192)
from pickle import load 
features=load(open('/home/jeevitha/8_8_192_features_mean/0lh_UWF9ZP4_148_155.pkl','rb'))
feat=np.array(features)
print(feat.shape)

Comment: dunno what the rest of the code does, but it does work for me:`zeros = np.zeros([8,8,192])
pickle.dump(zeros, open('/tmp/uiae', 'wb'))
x = pickle.load(open('/tmp/uiae', 'rb'))
x.shape
Out[51]: (8, 8, 192)`

Answer (score 0):

In case of multiple dimensions you have to provide a tuple,
see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)

np.zeros((8,8,192)) is what you want, or np.zeros([8,8,192]) as filthysocks said

Comment: actually 8,8,192 is a shape to store a pickle file of image,  both of the format shows the same result as (0,)

Answer (score 0):

it sorted,

```
 dir_path='/home/jeevitha/8_8_192_features'
    #count = 1
    for name in os.listdir(dir_path):
    #count += 1
    video_id = name.split('.')[0]
    fname='/home/jeevitha/8_8_192_features'+video_id+'.pkl'
    if not (os.path.isfile(fname) ):
        video_file_path=os.path.join(dir_path, name)
        features=open(video_file_path, 'rb')  
        features=list() 
        new_features = np.zeros([8,8,192])
        for i in features:
            new_features+=features[i]
        new_features=new_features/len(features)
        dump(new_features,open(fname,'wb'))
```